# Unexpected token: <EOL>. (BCE0043)

Tags: c#

I have this code in C # that asks to write the numbers from 1 to 100 on the screen. The problem is that it throws the error above with the while brace and I don't know how to correct it

```
namespace proof

import System
import System.Collections
import System.Drawing
import System.Windows.Forms

partial class MainForm:
    public def constructor():
        // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
        InitializeComponent()
    
     private def Button1Click(sender as object, e as System.EventArgs):
                int x = 1;
                while (x <= 100)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(x);
                    Console.WriteLine(" - ");
                    x = x + 1;
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
       pass
[STAThread]
public def Main(argv as (string)) as void:
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false)
    Application.Run(MainForm())
```

Comment: you need to create a console application not a winform one

Comment: Huh, that's not valid C# syntax. Why is there a `def` keyword? Why is there a `:` after the end of the declaration? Where are the braces around the method body? What is that `STAThread` attribute doing there?

Comment: You have got to get a book or tutorial. You can't just make up your own syntax.

Comment: Why are you using def? And as? Why are you mixing Python and VB?

Comment: What. Is. That. Code?! That's literally C# and Python mixed together, none of which is valid syntax.

Comment: One moment!. I am not making up any syntax. What happens is that I was not paying attention and I was creating an application in Boo language instead of C#.

Answer (score 0):

do this by creating a **Console** application

```
private static void ReadNumbers()
  {
    int x = 1;
    while (x <= 100)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        Console.WriteLine(" - ");
        x = x + 1;
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: It's not what I want. I want to work with a form that when pressing a button prints on the form. I don't want to create a console application

Comment: but where do you want to the user to input values a hundred times  ? in Textbox ?

Comment: I want to print the numbers in the form

Comment: use a listbox to display numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Windows Forms project.

Add a Button to the form.

Add an event handler for button1.Click.

Add a ListBox to the form.

Add the numbers to the ListBox.

**And don't mix syntax(es)!**

---

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int x = 1;
    while (x <= 100) {
        listBox1.Items.Add(x);
        ++x;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not inventing or guessing syntax, the button code header is the one that appears by default in SharpDevelop. Keep marking error.

Comment: @AlejandroCaro — Why are you using SharpDevelop? Use Visual Studio, there's literally a free Community version. Visual Studio is designed for .NET development.

Comment: Ah, are you using Mac?

Comment: No, I using Windows 10

Comment: Then why are you using SharpDevelop?